# Insert nested element

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to wrap the contents of an element with another element using CSS?

I am looking for a mechanism similar to `:before` but which will take this HTML

```
<div class="wrap-content">
    content
</div>
```

and turn it into this:

```
<div class="wrap-content">
    <p class="wrapper">
        content
    </p>
</div>
```

---

Why I need this: I have `div`s with `float: right` but the content should be aligned left. I can achieve this by inserting a `<p style="text-align:left"></p>` around the contents.

However I'm writing content in markdown for a browser presentation framework where I have a short syntax for inserting the outer `div`, adding the `p` manually would mean a lot of copy and paste (and clutter). If there is a different (smarter) way to do this I would of course also be happy.

Comment: There is no way to wrap inner elements with css, but not sure how adding that inner element allows you to align left ([see this - there is no difference](http://jsfiddle.net/3ysormpz/2/)) - how come you can't just align left on the parent?  Please can you create a [mcve]

Comment: If the content is aligned right then the issue must be somewhere else cuz `float` doesnt have to do anything with content alignment. Or am i missing something
?

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: @Pete, Ryan.Hunt: you guys are right, testing it on a clean example showed that the float doesn't actually affect the alignment. Turns out I was reusing a class name that the framework defines in a different way. I changed the name and now it works -- thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible using css only, you probably neet some javascript.

Otherwise, if you are able to update the outer div, you can use the :before and add an attribute to the outer div to use its value as the content of :before, something like this:

```
<div class="wrap-content" data-content="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap-content:before{
  content: attr(data-content);
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```